# bash aliases set in while loop not persisting

Tags: bash, sh, alias

Okay, I've written a shell script to read a file with the format:

shortcut1 /path/to/directory1
shortcut2 /path/to/directory2

and its supposed to read the file and build aliases such that typing shortcut1 cd's me into the mapped directory. The problem is, any of the aliases set in the loop don't persist outside of the script.

Firstly I tried just running the script.

> . ./build_shortcuts.sh "~/.shortcuts"

where the file ~/.shortcuts contains

> dl    ~/Downloads
>   music /music
>   dtop  ~/Desktop

This didn't work. Then I tried setting some aliases outside of the loop. Such as alias hello='world'; alias world='hellob'. I reran the script, typed alias to get a list of aliases and it did include hello and world as aliases, but not any of those set in the loop.

Then I thought maybe the loop isn't setting them at all, so I added alias as the final command in the script so it would print out the aliases at the end; in this case it did include the aliases but they still didn't persist in my session.

build_shortcuts.sh

```sh
script="$(cat $@ | sed -r -e 's/#[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$//' -e '/^\s+/s/^\s+//' -e '/^\s*$/d' -)"
# strip comments, entry level indentation & empty lines (in that order) from filestream

echo "${script}" | while read shortcut; do
    cut=$(echo  "${shortcut}" | awk '{         print $1 }')
    dest=$(echo "${shortcut}" | awk '{ $1=nil; print $0 }')
    dest="${dest:1}" # trim leading whitespace character

    alias "${cut}" &>/dev/null

    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        echo "Warning: shortcut \"${cut}\" already exists" >&2
        continue # by default, skip overwriting shortcuts
    fi

    echo alias ${cut}="'cd ${dest}'"
    alias "${cut}"="'cd ${dest}'"
done
```

I want the aliases set in the loop within the script to exist outside of the script. Currently they don't.

I'm running on "GNU bash, version 5.0.7(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)" on arch linux.

Comment: Be aware that `~` will not expand if it's inside quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the Bash manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) (the section on *Pipelines*):

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in a subshell)

Since the loop is done as part of a pipe, it will be a subshell, and the alias command you do in the subshell will only be set for that subshell.

A possible work-around would be to save the aliases to a list, and then perform the actual `alias` commands in a second loop, a loop which is not part of a pipe or a subshell.

Answer (score 0):

Your script can be reduced a bit: it doesn't need to call out to so many external tools.

```
while read -r cut dest; do
    if alias "${cut}" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "Warning: shortcut \"${cut}\" already exists" >&2
    else        
        echo alias ${cut}="'cd ${dest}'"
        alias "${cut}"="'cd ${dest}'"
    fi
done < <(
    sed -E -e 's/#[A-Za-z0-9 ]*$//' -e '/^\s+/s/^\s+//' -e '/^\s*$/d' "$@"
)
```

after "done", I'm redirecting input from a process substitution: this avoids the "while read" loop from running in a subshell.